# AMP validator: reports errors while code should be perfectly ok

Tags: amp-html

I'm starting to explore the possibilities offered by AMP and I have implemented a couple of features. They all work fine when I load them but when I use the validator proposed by Google (https://search.google.com/test/amp), I get a bunch of error messages that I haven't managed to fix.

1. The mandatory tag 'head > style[amp-boilerplate]' is missing or incorrect.

Well, that's strange because I have copied/pasted exactly what was in the documentation and still, the validator doesn't find it in my code. You can check it by yourself here: http://www.gpu-central.com/en/

2. The mandatory tag 'noscript enclosure for boilerplate' is missing or incorrect.

Here is another example of something I copied in my code but the validator doesn't find it

3. The tag 'head > style[amp-boilerplate]' is missing or incorrect, but required by 'noscript > style[amp-boilerplate]'.

Same as above

4. The parent tag of tag 'meta name=viewport' is 'body', but it can only be 'head'.

The parent of viewport is head but apparently the validator doesn't see it

It looks like their regex can't find the right tags in my code but I don't really see why.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks

Laurent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

be sure to save it utf-8 encoded.
here is some working sample i did some years ago, together with some notes:

https://github.com/womd/amp_product_page
see it in action here:
https://shop.hepf.com/Service/amp_product/14178/943/2 ( url might get removed over time )

cheers

Comment: Hi Womd, thanks! I also suspected this but I'm not sure it's the only problem. I have converted page encoding to UTF8 but as my cms is making many inclusions from different files, one of those files may still be in another encoding. I know for sure that the file containing the AMP code is in UTF8, should it be in UTF8 without BOM? Thanks

Comment: sry, don't remember anymore ;( ... but what helped was checking result of html-validator - it does not speak amp - but could point you to some things to check: 
https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gpu-central.com%2Fen%2F
...some apache-module / your cms changeing headers - browser will not show ... try getting it with curl .... !  Just noticed something: open the url with IE ..press F12 for dev mode ... see the characters bevore <!Doctype ... maybee that's an issue !!

Comment: Hi Womd, I managed to solve the issue by using UTF8 without BOM. I still have another issue but will open another topic for this. Thanks!